# Question: can the title of my setting differ from the title of my executable/application?

Tags: iphone, settings

I'm developing an application which has a Settings pane, following the 
AppPrefs sample by Apple. 
If my application is named AppPrefs, this is the exact name/prompt/ 
title the Settings application will provide. 
Is there anyway to make this change? Can my executable somehow be 
named (for example) Application1 and my Settings named "Settings for 
App1"? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortuntely, nope, due to the why the settings system works.  From Apple's [iPhone Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide.pdf):

> When the Settings application launches, it checks each custom application for the presence of a settings bundle. For each custom bundle it finds, it loads that bundle and displays the corresponding application’s name and icon in the Settings main page. When the user taps the row belonging to your application, Settings loads the Root.plist Settings Page file for your settings bundle and uses that file to display your application’s main page of preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it used to be possible by adding a "Title" key with a string for the name of the preferences in the Root.plist (e.g. in Mark and LaMarche '09, p311).  But this no longer appears to work.  I think this is a problem because the Bundle display name is sometimes a shortened version of your app to fit under the icon in the spring board.